# Transform a column of type string to an array/record i.e. nesting a column

Tags: sql, nested, google-bigquery

I am trying to get calculate and retrieve some indicators from mutiple tables I have in my dataset on bigquery. I am want to invoke nesting on `sfam` which is a column of strings which I can't do for now i.e. it could have values or be null. So the goal is to transform that column into an array/record...that's the idea that came to mind and I have no idea how to go about doing it.

The `product` and `cart` are grouped by `key_web`, `dat_log`, `univ`, `suniv`, `fam` and `sfam`.

The data is broken down into universe refered to as `univ` which is composed of sub-universe refered to as `suniv`. Sub-universes contain families refered to as 'fam' which may or may not have sub-families refered to as `sfam`. I want to invoke nesting on `prd.sfam` to reduce the resulting columns.

The data is collected from Google Analytics for insight into website trafic and users activities.

I am trying to get information and indicators about each visitor, the amount of time he/she spent on particular pages, actions taken and so on. The resulting table gives me the sum of time spent on those pages, sum of total number of visits for a single day and a breakdown to which category it belongs, thus the `univ`, `suniv`, `fam` and `sfam` columns which are of type string (the sfam could be null since some sub-universes suniv only have families `fam`and don't go down to a sub-family level `sfam`.

- `dat_log`: refers to the date
- `nrb_fp`: number of views for a product page
- `tps_fp`: total time spent on said page

I tried different methods that I found online but none worked, so I post my code and problem in hope of finding guidance and a solution !

A simpler query would be:

```
 select
        prd.key_web
        , dat_log
        , prd.nrb_fp
        , prd.tps_fp
        , prd.univ
        , prd.suniv
        , prd.fam
        , prd.sfam
    from product as prd
    left join cart as cart
        on prd.key_web = cart.key_web
        and prd.dat_log = cart.dat_log
        and prd.univ = cart.univ
        and prd.suniv = cart.suniv
        and prd.fam = cart.fam
        and prd.sfam = cart.sfam
```

And this is a sample result of the query for the last 6 columns in text and images:

Again, I want to get a column of array as `sfam` where I have all the string values of `sfam` even nulls.

I limited the output to only only the last 6 columns, the first 3 are the row, `key_web` and `dat_log`. Each `fam` is composed of several `sfam` or none (null), I want to be able to do nesting on either the `fam` or `sfam`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, in BigQuery you cannot output array which holds NULL, but if for some reason you need to preserve them somehow - the workaround is to create array of structs as opposed to arrays of single elements

For example (BigQuery Standard SQL) if you try to execute below

```
SELECT ['a', 'b', NULL] arr1, ['x', NULL, NULL] arr2
```

you will get error: `Array cannot have a null element; error in writing field arr1`

While if you will try below

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(val1, val2)) arr
FROM UNNEST(['a', 'b', NULL]) val1 WITH OFFSET
JOIN UNNEST(['x', NULL, NULL]) val2 WITH OFFSET
USING(OFFSET)
```

you get result

```
Row     arr.val1    arr.val2     
1       a           x    
        b           null     
        null        null
```

As you can see - approaching this way - you can have have even both elements as NULL

Comment: Thank you very much ! This is very insightful and helpful !!

Answer (score 2):

> I want to get a column of array as `sfam` where I have all the string values of `sfam` even nulls.

This is not possible in BigQuery.  As the documentation explains:

> Currently, BigQuery has two following limitations with respect to NULLs and ARRAYs:
>
> **BigQuery raises an error if query result has ARRAYs which contain NULL elements**, although such ARRAYs can be used inside the query.

That is, your result set cannot contain an array with `NULL` elements.

Comment: Okay, I see. Since fam column doesn't have nulls...how to pull it off using it instead ?